# Set caching for a Cordova / PhoneGap application

Tags: html, cordova

Out of morbid curiosity, I ran the Chrome audit on my PhoneGap / Cordova app, and got the following message:

```
Leverage browser caching (85)
The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime:
[list of image files, etc.]
```

I'm curious to know where the cache timeouts are specified for a PhoneGap app. There's no real server at play here, right? In my case, the image files are relative to the main index.html on the client / mobile device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-posted this question on the PhoneGap Google group. Here's the answer I got (later confirmed by Jesse Monroy):

> Personally, I see little reason to cache a local resource. Also keep in mind that Chrome's audit is intended for web use, not geared for hybrid apps.

Makes sense to me. Since your resources are bundled on the client / mobile device, there's not much point in caching. You aren't dealing with the latency issues you'd find with resources coming from a server.

So for those looking at the Chrome audits and scratching your head about this item in your results, this warning can be safely ignored for local resources.